# PHP : Matching an IP in a range between? (IPv4 and IPv6)

Tags: php, ip, range

Is it a good idea to use `inet_pton()` function to match an IP in a specific range? And is it good to use it for both IPv4 and IPv6 ?

For example:

```
$start = inet_pton('192.168.0.1');
$end = inet_pton('195.200.0.200');
$ip = inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if($ip >= $start && $ip <= $end) {
       echo 'in range';
}
else {
echo 'not in range';
}
```

Comment: inet_pton — Converts a human readable IP address to its packed in_addr representation. What should be good or bad there?

Comment: Is it a good practice to use it for such purposes and most important is it reliable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's  [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function. It will convert IPv4 to numbers.

Try this code:-

```
$start = ip2long('192.168.0.1');
$end = ip2long('195.200.0.200');
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

For both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses use this function for global use.

```
function ipaddress_to_ipnumber($ipaddress) {
    $pton = @inet_pton($ipaddress);
    if (!$pton) { return false; }
    $number = '';
    foreach (unpack('C*', $pton) as $byte) {
        $number .= str_pad(decbin($byte), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return base_convert(ltrim($number, '0'), 2, 10);
  }

$start = ipaddress_to_ipnumber("192.168.178.255");
$end = ipaddress_to_ipnumber('195.200.0.200');
$ip = ipaddress_to_ipnumber($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about IPv6 addresses? It seems that this function accepts only IPv4 format.

Comment: Yes, ip2long() can only handle ipv4.